# Nested for loops to compare char arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to compare the char Array c with s, in order to find out if c does not contain any element of s at index i. Therefore I am incrementing i and k at the same time, but it does not work for me.

The code should check if the entered number belongs to the decimal system (for example: 70, and 12B). For 70 it should be checked if at index zero and one (char[] c) the chars lie within the char array s. For 12B, index zero, one and two would be checked in char array s, only to find out that char array s does not contain index two ("B"). I hope I could make it a bit more clear.

```
public static boolean isDecimal(String number) {
    boolean t = true;
    char[] s = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    char[] c = number.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
            if (c[i] != s[k]) {
                t = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Break the loop after `t = false;` i.e. do it as `t = false; break;`. Also, what's not working for you?

Comment: `return number.matches("\\d+");`

Comment: Your `char[] s` has 10 values, but you're just checking the first 9 values `k < 9` (0-8). You should change it to something like `k < c.length()` or `k <= 9` or `k < 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are better ways to check whether a given String consists of digits, only. But let's 'debug' your code.

In pseudo code you're trying to do the following:

```
public static boolean isDecimal(String number) {
    char[] s = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    char[] c = number.toCharArray();

    boolean t = true;
    for (int i = 0; t && i < number.length(); i++) {
        t = s contains c[i]
    }

    return t;
}
```

The problem is, that your inner loop doesn't test if `s contains c[i]`, but if there's at least one digit that is different from `c[i]` (which always evaluates to `true`, of course).

Another (minor) problem is, that you don't test all elements of s, because of the condition `k < 9` in your inner loop.

How to fix this? Basically, you've got to invert the logic:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int k = 0; !found && k < s.length; k++) { // note the correct condition
    found = (c[i] == s[k]);
}
```

Having this, `found == true` if (and only if) `s` contains `c[i]`. Next, you can tell for sure that if `found == false`, `number` contains non-digits.

Let's put all together:

```
public static boolean isDecimal(String number) {
    char[] s = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    char[] c = number.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int k = 0; !found && k < s.length; k++) {
            found = (c[i] == s[k]);
        }
        if (!found) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Needless to say, that there are better options to perform this check, but I guess this is just code to learn something.

Comment: By the way, one of the better ways you speak of might be simply: `"12" .codePoints().allMatch( Character :: isDigit )` as seen [running on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/NT1Jb3). (And, good work on this educational Answer.)

Comment: @BasilBourque, thanks and yes, that's a good way. Another was shown by Elliot Frisch in the comments on the question. Even just using Character#isDigit would simplify the code above and it's hard to refrain from using those methods when answering educational questions :-)